# Regex find replace match string and remove everything from the first instance of a character

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am working in Visual Studio Code and I have a very large JSON file to which I would like to make some edits.
In all instances where I have a line that starts `"category":`  I would like to find the first instance of `>` and remove it and everything that follows excluding the final comma.
Then as a separate query, I would like to do something similar. I would like to find the last instance of > and remove it and everything that precedes it

So for example for the first query

`"category": "Level1 > Level2 > Level3",`

or

`"category": "Level1 > Level2",`

Would be replaced with

`"category": "Level1",`
thus stripping out everything from the first onwards `>`

and for the second query

`"subCategory": "Level1 > Level2 > Level3",`

Would be replaced with

`"subCategory": "Level3",`
basically stripping out everything from the last `>` back to the `"`

"Level1", "Level2" etc could be anything

My best efforts so far have been to Find

`"category": ?(.+)`

which finds the lines OK, but provides me with nothing to use as a replacement. I should know this, but Regex does seem to take an age to sink in.

Comment: Shouldn't `"subCategory": "Level1 > Level2 > Level3",` be replaced with `"subCategory": "Level1",`?

Comment: No, sorry if i's confusing I am looking two different find/replacements. For the lines beginning category, I only want the first item and for the subCategory I only want the last. I will try and reword it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer after much trial and error and thanks to an unknown user who posted a partial solution here, then deleted it very soon after. I didn't take note of the user name, unfortunately.

For the first query: find any line that starts with `"category":` and remove anything after and including the first `>` up to the trailing comma. It ended up like so:

In Visual Studio Code's find/replace dialogue (Ctrl+H)

**Find:** `("category":\s*)("[^>]*[^>\s])\s*>.*(",)`

**Replace:** `$1$2$3`

The second query: Find any line that starts with `"subCategory":` and remove everything else up to and including the last `>` I used:

**Find:** `("subCategory":\s*").*[$>]*>\s(.*",)`

**Replace:**  `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a little simpler than your regex's.

For the first query, see [regex101 demo](https://(?%3C=category%22:.*)%5Cs*%3E.*(?=%22,)):

Find: `(?<=\bcategory":.*)\s*>.*(?=",)`
Replace: with nothing

For the second query, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UtaXZx/1):

Find: `(?<=\bsubCategory":\s*")(.*>\s*)`
Replace: with nothing

These will work in the Find in a file widget, but not for a search across multiple files - due to the lookbehind of a non-fixed length.

If you want it to work in a search across files then use:

Find: `(\bcategory":.*?)\s*>.*(?=",)`
Replace: `$1`

Find: `(\bsubCategory":\s*")(.*>\s*)`
Replace: `$1`